# Automatically indent the code without messing the tracking of changes in svn

Tags: svn, astyle

I need to run astyle in a project with several source files. There's not a common IDE used by all developers, they develop in vi, gedit, Netbeans, Eclipse, etc. So I can't use a configuration file for indentation. In order to keep a standard in the code indentation I want to run an script (probably in a server) that everyday executes astyle for each source file and commits the changes. But I'm afraid I will loose track of who has made the last changes in the code.

Can I configure svn to keep information of who made the changes before the execution of astyle?

Thx.

Comment: While more work to figure out how to configure all of the editors to use the same "style", a lot less hassle and confusion for the developers not needing to update after committing.

Comment: Actually they don't need to update after commiting because the script would run once a day (at midnight perhaps).

Comment: Still, makes more sense to have the developers configure their tools to adhere to set standards if the standard is so important.

Comment: Believe me, we have tried this a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SVN already automatically always keep this information (see `svn log -l 1 FILE`)
- You have to remember old committer of every (modified && commited after astyle) file and restore (in added by astyle-script revisions) previous commiter - it can be special post-commit hook, in which you can do *almost anything*

Hints:

1. Build changelists (before commits), in which you'll collect files per committer
2. Commit astyle-related changes under special separated user, using changelists from p.1 or, if you know user's name|password, commit as this user (`--username` + `--password` options of `svn ci`)
3. Permanent post-commit hook (maybe even pre-commit) can be executed only for *special committer* and will change author of commit|transaction with `propset`

Anyway, administrative reactions and sanctions ("Play by the rules or went out") is more right and short way